How to Set Separate Database Connection Strings for Azure App Service Deployment Slots
I have an ASP.NET Core app deployed in Azure App Service, with both staging and production deployment slots. Currently, the app uses a single Azure SQL Database connection string stored in Azure Key Vault.
In my Program.cs file, I retrieve the connection string as follows:
var sqlConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetSection("sqlConnectionString").Value;

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'MyAppContext' not found.")));

The sqlConnectionString is not stored in appsettings.json; it is fetched directly from the Key Vault.
I need to connect the production deployment slot to a different Azure SQL Database. This should ensure that when I swap slots, the production instance of the app connects to the production database.
I added a new Connection String named sqlConnectionString of type SQLAzure under the Environment Variables in the production slot settings. However, this did not work, and the production slot still connects to the staging database.

In Program.cs I added the following code:
var isDevelopment = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment();
var sqlConnectionString = "";

if (isDevelopment)
{
    sqlConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetSection("sqlConnectionString").Value;
}
else
{
    sqlConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnectionString");
}

In development mode, I get the connection string from Key Vault using the GetSection method. In staging and production modes, I get the connection string using the GetConnectionString method.
Additionally, I made the following improvements in Azure App Service:

I added the sqlConnectionString to the Connection Strings section for both the Production and Staging deployment slots.
I added an environment variable named ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in both the staging and production environments. For the staging environment, the value is set to Staging, and for the production environment, the value is set to Production.

As a result, my development and staging environments are now connected to one database, while the production environment is connected to a separate production database.

When you create a new slot. You will get Environment variable option to add new App settings or Connection string for the slot, as shown below:

To stop changes for a app settings/ To separate app setting for particular slot setting, use  the option Deployment slot setting

For reference check this MSDocs.

To configure an app setting or connection string to stick to a specific slot (not swapped), go to the Configuration page for that slot. Add or edit a setting, and then select deployment slot setting. Selecting this check box tells App Service that the setting isn't swappable.

I am fetching a simple value application setting value in different slots.
without enabling the Deployment slot setting
OUTPUT:
Before Swap :-
production slot

staging slot

when you swap you can see all the slot settings enable values are available during swap. when you do not enable the Deployment Slot Setting

After Swap :-
production slot

After enabling the Deployment slot setting

As you can see now sql_conn settings are not available in option during slot swap because that app setting is fixed for the slots.


Thank you for your answer, that is how I did initially, and this did not work for me.
I will post my solution below

You can use different appsettings.json for different environments.
appsettings.json

Or
Azure Portal

